# Use AVERAGEIF across multiple cell ranges in a worksheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using **AVERAGEIF** using the following to return the answer

```
=AVERAGEIF('Sheet 2'!H3:K10,I9,'Sheet 2'!K3:K10)
```

This works well if I have all the information in one sheet, however I have the information in two sheets it no longer works.  I have tried creating a SUPER RANGE as it work using contiguous cells in both sheets. I have been asked not to combine the two sheets.

```
=AVERAGEIF('Sheet 1:Sheet 2'!H3:L10,I9,'Sheet 1:Sheet 2'!K3:K10)
```

However I get a **#VALUE** error.  This is potentially because for that particular row there is no match for I9 in one of the sheets.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is `Sheet 1:Sheet 2`? You want the same range from both sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Averageif won't take more than one of each criteria and averageifs won't take more than one range to average.

You can get around it by getting creative-

```
1   dog
2   cat
3   cat
4   dog
5   cat
1   cat
2   cat
3   dog
4   dog
5   dog
=AVERAGEIF(B1:B10,"cat",A1:A10)
```

results the same as

```
1   dog   1   cat
2   cat   2   cat
3   cat   3   dog
4   dog   4   dog
5   cat   5   dog
=(SUM(SUMIF(B1:B5,"cat",A1:A5),SUMIF(D1:D5,"cat",C1:C5))/SUM(COUNTIF(B1:B5,"cat"),COUNTIF(D1:D5,"cat")))
```